# Python 3.4 and 2.7 installation no Script folder and no pip installed

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

I was doing a fresh installation for `Python 2.7.9` and `3.4.3` on `Win7 X64` today, and I found that there is no `Script` folder in `Python27` and `Python34` folder as first child level folder, but there is one in `Tools`. However, I couldn't find `pip` within that Script folder, although `pip` should be installed with `Python` by default. The other I was doing the same installation for my other PC and laptop, there was `Script` folder (as first level child folder in `Python27` and `Python34`) containing `pip`. So what is going on? how to install `pip` and maybe other useful scripts this way?

[EDIT] I tried `python -m ensurepip` in `Python34`. I got the following errors:

```
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Collecting setuptools
 Exception:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\daiyue\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppvmc8dv1\pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-
any.whl\pip\basecommand.py", line 232, in main
  status = self.run(options, args)
File "C:\Users\daiyue\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppvmc8dv1\pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-
any.whl\pip\commands\install.py", line 339, in run
  requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
File "C:\Users\daiyue\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppvmc8dv1\pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-
any.whl\pip\req\req_set.py", line 333, in prepare_files
  upgrade=self.upgrade,
File "C:\Users\daiyue\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppvmc8dv1\pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-
any.whl\pip\index.py", line 326, in find_requirement
  file_locations, url_locations = self._sort_locations(locations)
File "C:\Users\daiyue\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppvmc8dv1\pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-
any.whl\pip\index.py", line 158, in _sort_locations
  sort_path(os.path.join(path, item))
File "C:\Users\daiyue\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppvmc8dv1\pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-
any.whl\pip\index.py", line 139, in sort_path
  if mimetypes.guess_type(url, strict=False)[0] == 'text/html':
File "C:\Python34\lib\mimetypes.py", line 287, in guess_type
  init()
File "C:\Python34\lib\mimetypes.py", line 348, in init
  db.read_windows_registry()
File "C:\Python34\lib\mimetypes.py", line 255, in read_windows_registry
  with _winreg.OpenKey(hkcr, subkeyname) as subkey:
TypeError: OpenKey() argument 2 must be str without null characters or None,  not str
```

[EDIT] The problem is due to multiple null Registry keys in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` that make `read_windows_registry()` in `mimetypes.py` searches failed. Here is the post that leads to the solution:

[Python ‘pip’ and Windows registry corruption](http://www.swarley.me.uk/blog/2014/04/23/python-pip-and-windows-registry-corruption/)

thanks

Comment: Why do you think that pip should be installed with Python by default? It is not.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: You use the bundled pip as `python -m pip install SomePackage`. See https://docs.python.org/3/installing/ for further information how to use the respective pip for python3 and python2 if you have both versions installed.

Comment: @yole it is stated on the pip website - "Python 2.7.9 and later (on the python2 series), and Python 3.4 and later include pip by default"

Comment: Ah, indeed. I wasn't aware it was added to 2.7.9.

Comment: @halex I tried `python -m pip install SomePackage`, but `No module named pip`. I was trying the command in `Python34`

Comment: pip is a package, like setuptools is. many installation guides (like the one at webfaction) teach you assuming setuptools is not installed on your system. This is because such tools are __not__ installed, by default, in any Python installation. However, there are many distributions which give you such packages when you install them. The Python(x,y) distribution is one of them (althought I think pip is not included there, but take it as an example).

Comment: Deleting registry keys with embedded nulls (`RegDelNull -s`) fixed this for me. See https://bugs.python.org/issue22028

Comment: I think this is more an installer issue than a system one if using default install paths.  I DLed what I thought was the correct 2.7 installer from python.org (found through google), got these issues.  Then followed the links from the home page to DL 2.7 and it worked.

Answer (score 15):

If you used the PSF (python.org) .msi Windows installers, pip (and dependencies) should be installed in pythonxy/Lib/site-packages for 3.4.0+ and 2.7.9+.  There should also be pythonxy/Scripts containing about 5 .exes.  This is the last part of the install process.  A command prompt window should briefly appear. Perhaps you did not have [ ] install pip checked when doing the installs (although this should have been checked by default).  Perhaps there was an error that you missed.

In any case, you should have pythonxy/Lib/ensurepip/* present for both 2.7 and 3.4 and you should be able to run this module now.  In Command Prompt, try `python -m ensurepip` in both .../python27 and .../python34.

Comment: Hi, I tried `python -m ensurepip`, but got some errors listed in the OP. `C:\Pythonxy\Lib\site-packages` contains nothing but a `README` file. BTW, what is `PSF`? I downloaded `Windows` installers for `2.7` and `3.4`.

Comment: Python Software Foundation, which operates xyz.python.org sites.  I saw your post on python-list.  The error message suggest that arg 2 is a string *with* a null, which seems like a bug somewhere.  If no answer here or there, perhaps worth a bug report on bugs.python.org.

Comment: python -m ensurepip ---user to get around permissions issues for me

Answer (score 10):

Had the same issue, reinstalling didn't help.

Finally fixed it by running `python -m ensurepip` as **administrator**.

Comment: This command did not work until I changed `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to the broken Python installation directory (the variable was set by another Python installation which was conflicting with my broken one).

Answer (score 5):

This problem is a official bug: [Issue23604](https://bugs.python.org/issue23604) .

I had encountered the same problem, and fixed it successfully using the method in
[Swarley's Blog](http://www.swarley.me.uk/blog/2014/04/23/python-pip-and-windows-registry-corruption/).

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue today while trying to install Python 2.7.13 in my computer; after some investigation I realized that v.3.60 ("Anaconda") was already present (it came along with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, which I've installed a couple weeks ago).

I suspected of some path mismatch in the registry, so I tried removing both Python v. 3.60 and 2.17, and cleaning up the Registry by deleting the *HKCU\Software\Python* key (which, due to some reason, was still present).
After this, I was able to correctly install version 2.7.13, and this time the \scripts folder is present, with all the expected contents.

I don't know if installing v. 3.6 again would cause any problem: I'm not going to try this for the time since I'm currently developing for v.2.7.

Hope this can be of some help, anyway.

Max - Italy

---

EDIT:
I've made some further investigation and think I've discovered the reason why (in my case), the \Scripts folder was missing: the path where I was going to install Python is in virtual drive.

In my computer I only have one partition (C:), and i've mapped a folder (C:\Development) as D:, then I tried to install Python on D:\Python27; apparently this is not "good" and causes some problem in the installer.

After discovering that, I tried installing to the real path, and now everything seems to be OK.

Max.

Answer (score 2):

Based on a combination of whats here, and what I found elsewhere, here is how I fixed it:

Uninstall whatever is installed already.
Go to regedit and HKLM/SOFTWARE/Python and delete the whole python section.
Reinstall Python

This installed with the scripts folder this time.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved by installing Python 2.7.13

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2713/

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10. I had this issue while installing Python 2.7 into C:/Program Files/Python27 .. I think in this case it was a path issue. Fix was to do an install into C:/Python27, copy the Scripts folder from that installation to the installation in C:/Program Files/Python27. Everything else (including the paths to Python and Scripts) was fine.

Answer (score 1):

Guess what? In case you have **NetBeans** (or probably **GlassFish**) installed, then it could break installation for **pip**!

*Details:* there's [a bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=251538) in NetBeans installer that could sometimes break the Windows registry in a way that's not expected by other installers.

[@J3soon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44593979/2684760) was close, but [Swarley's blog post](http://www.swarley.me.uk/blog/2014/04/23/python-pip-and-windows-registry-corruption/) haven't fixed the problem in my environment, *because it wasn't a null character but was another kind of registry corruption*.

And here's how I got rid of the issue. Run the following PowerShell script:

```
$local_key = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
$machine_key = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
$machine_key6432 = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
$items = Get-ChildItem @($local_key, $machine_key, $machine_key6432)
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

foreach ($item in $items) {
    Write-Output $item.PSPath
    $null = Get-ItemProperty $item.PSPath
}
```

It will write the registry key names to the output. In case it prints an error, **take the one last key it printed** and remove that from the registry (using PowerShell or `regedit` or whatever tool you prefer).

After that, reinstall Python, and it should install pip as intended.

Answer (score 1):

It is permission issue. I have both python 2 and 3 installed under

`C:\Program Files\python\2.7.16`

`C:\Program Files\python\3.7.2`

Python 2 installer is msi, so there is no `run as admin` option when install it

Python 3 installer is exe, there is `run as admin` option.

As the results, python 2 installed without `scripts` and `pip.exe` and python 3 installed successfully.

To fix this, simply give the `full` permission to `everyone` on

`C:\Program Files\python\` and install python 2 again. then change the permission back.

That's it.

Comment: How do you give it full administrator permission?
Who do you give the permission to? The python website? The installer as it's installing?

Answer (score 0):

I am using python 3.6.2 and faced a similar issue of missing scripts folder(also pip script) in python folder. I have done following things to add scripts folder again to python.

1. Goto - Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features
         then look for python program and try to uninstall it. A pop window 
         will appear which shows the following image.

[Image Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1muf.jpg)

Try to REPAIR the installed program that should fix the issue.

2. Otherwise click on MODIFY and tick on pip check box and Add Python to environment variables checkbox, then install it. This should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing this issue. I solved it by doing the following steps:

1. Uninstall python. (you can use the installer(python-2.7.xx.msi) to perform the uninstall. Select the option 'Remove Python'on double clicking the installer.)
2. Edit the environment variable 'Path', and remove the python directory path. ( To change the environment variable, right click on 'This PC', click properties, click 'Advanced System Properties' ->Environment Variables)
3. Remove the environment variable 'Python Path' if present.
4. Now reinstall python.

It will work !!!

Answer (score 0):

Actually Scipts folder will not create after installing python, you have to manually create this folder and then install pip, then you can find the required files in this directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced the same problem which i managed to solve. The problem is when you install the python in default configuration then it installs the python folder in the "c:\user\Appdata......" which is lengthy and hard to find . To avoid it first uninstall  the python 3.7 completely from the system from the control panel ->uninstall program. Then install it again with the option " customize installation". On the next page change the default location to C:/Python/Python37-32 and select the required check boxes and click install. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This Command works fine for me:

```sh
python -m ensurepip
```

> Looking in links: C:\Users\kjangala\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvd4_442i
>   Collecting setuptools
>   Collecting pip
>   Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip
>   Successfully installed pip-19.0.3 setuptools-40.8.0

Comment: got "No module named ensurepip"

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after getting a new computer and restoring my appdata folder (an enterprise system did this automatically for me). Somehow some old metadata in my `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python` folder made the Scripts folder inside end up empty when I reinstalled Python.

I deleted this folder and uninstalled/reinstalled Python, and everything is working again.

**Edit**: I also had to delete `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Python` to resolve another similar error. Interestingly, this one didn't get recreated on the reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, 
Download this file [Get Pip](https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/blob/master/templates/pre-18.1.py). Save it in your local with the extension .py

To run in windows:

1.) Open cmd

2.) type "python" and check if python is been installed

3.) type "python filePath.py" (example if you saved your file in C drive go the particular folder and run the command - Here "filePath.py" is the filename you saved)

[command looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEai3.png)

4.) Cheers now it should work

5.) To check if pip installed properly type "pip --version"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (win 10, py 3.8.5, executable installer). The solution i've found is to install python to non-standard catalog (D:/ instead of windows user folder which is under access protection). In this case, the file "easy_install.exe" will be created in the Scripts folder. Then open console inside the folder and call "easy_install pip", this will install pip. After that just copy everything to the standard catalog and don't forget to change the environment variables.