# Python 2.7.11 pip not installed

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pip

I have Python 2.7.11 installed on my machine which to my understanding should come with pip, however when I check the `C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts\` directory there is no `pip.exe` present.

I have tried completely removing and reinstalling Python 2.7.11 without success.  Running the installer pip is set to be installed, but after the install pip is nowhere to be found.

I also have Python 3.4 installed which has pip as expected.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have a `pip2.7` command by any chance?

Comment: Is it in `Scripts` instead of `Tools\Scripts`?

Comment: @ChristianTernus There are no other pip variants in the `C:\Python27` directory.

Comment: @JohnGordon There is no `Scripts` folder only `Tools\Scripts`.  From what I've read I think that's normal for Python2

Comment: See [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47607594/2684760) as an another possible solution.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem - pip not installed - with python-2.7.16, Win10, installing for 'all users'. It was resolved when I allowed the MSI installer to target the default location (C:\Python27) rather than changing it to under Program Files (x86). I've no clue why this changed anything.

Answer (score 3):

[python2.7.11](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.11/python-2.7.11.amd64.msi) should install pip into c:\python27\scripts, you can take a look [here](http://screencast.com/t/xX6WwxdnNN)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I have no `C:\Python27\Scripts` directory.  Only `C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts`.

Comment: @user3794548 Have you tried the link using the link I've provided on my answer? That's the one I've used to show you the output.

Comment: I just tried it and unfortunately still no `Scripts/pip.exe`.

Comment: @user3794548, try `C:\Python27\python.exe -m ensurepip -v`. If that works, then I don't know what's going wrong at install time, short of something trivial like not actually selecting to install pip.

Comment: @user3794548, 2.7.12 was released 2 months ago. Is there a reason you're installing 2.7.11?

Comment: @eryksun That worked, thanks! 

I know that pip was selected during the multiple reinstall attempts I made, so it could not have been that (I also used the same installer and selected the same settings on another machine and had no problems).  If you present your answer as a solution I'll accept it. Thanks again, and thanks to all who commented!

Answer (score 3):

I used https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/  to make it install. Odd that an outside body has to make a tool to get pip to install. There is no mention of pip.pypa.io on the Python web site.
Although I got error messages, it did install, so check carefully.
You also may see a message suggesting that you upgrade to pip 9.0 with the command 'pip install --upgrade.' I highly recommend that.
Also, make sure you are in the directory where pip.exe is located when you run the commands. They don't tell you that, because they assume you know that, but we're not all geeks.

Comment: This worked for me, I was having issues related to https://bugs.python.org/issue22028 and blogged about here http://www.swarley.me.uk/blog/2014/04/23/python-pip-and-windows-registry-corruption/ none of the solution worked for me until I installed pip manually like instructed here https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Answer (score 2):

For people who are running into this issue, I have a Windows 10 x86 dev box that I use for exploit development, Python 2.7 was installed due to Immunity Debugger, this install did not include the new SSL package and did not include "pip".

There was no "C:\Python27\Scripts" folder which included pip. I did have a "C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts" folder which did not have pip installed.

I tired to install pip as suggested but did not work. Best way is to uninstall Python and install newest version, currently mine is 2.7.15 which came with pip as an option. This is what solved my issue, any older version of Python will need upgraded to support the SSL packages. You will receive the same errors when you try to install pip on an older version.

If you have reinstalled Python which included the SSL package and it still does not have pip, trying installing pip this way:

```
1. curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

2. python get-pip.py
```

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

This should work if you have a newer version of Python.

Once you have installed pip or newer version of python, go to "C:\Python27\Scripts" and you should see pip.exe.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed "**python-2.7.16**" in my windows 10 PC. **PIP** is installed under "**C:\Python27\Scripts**". One can add the "C:\Python27\Scripts" path to environment variable and then access pip command from command prompt.

To add the path in environment variable:

Control Panel\System and Security\System --> Advanced System Settings --> Advanced --> enviroment variables --> under system variable --> Path(variable name)

Answer (score 0):

Had the issue where no matter which version of python 2.7 I installed on windows 10 there was no pip.exe generated in the "Scripts" folder.

I solved it by ensuring that that MSI Installer file had Admin privileges before installing

Answer (score 0):

if pip is not installed you can use easy_install.exe to install pip and other modules
you can find easy install in

```
python -m easy_install pip
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue:

- Installed Python 27
- Tried to use pip, but failed with unrecognized command error
- Checked installation: no "C:\Python27\Scripts", only "C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts"

This issue happens only on some versions of Windows.

HOW TO FIX IT:

- Uninstall Python 27
- Reinstall Python 27, but unselect "pip" feature
- Check installation: no "C:\Python27\Scripts" as expected
- Start the installer again and use "Change Python"
- Set "pip" and "Add Python.exe to Path" features to be installed
- Check installation: "C:\Python27\Scripts" is now correctly present

So for some unknown reason, pip is not correctly installed on some versions of Windows if it is installed during default Python 27 setup. To fix this issue, pip must be installed afterwards using the "Change Python" setup.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same issue when install Python 2.7.9. The installer does not come with pip.

Solution:

- Install newer python2 x86 version: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/
- Then pip is located at C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe

Answer (score -1):

It happens on windows as you should have admin rights to install anything on disk C.
I have the same issue Scripts folder was not installed. I would sugest to instal it on disk D.